# ASP.Net MVC JQuery is undefined in IE8 but ok in Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web application which works perfectly in Chrome, but in IE8, I get undefined errors for my script files:
[image: ss1]
The scripts are all loaded in the correct order (View -> Source):
[image: ss2]
I'm not sure where to start diagnosing this - any ideas? (I thought IE8 was fairly modern).

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: According to [jQuery 2.0 DOCS](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)

`As promised, this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 browsers.`

Comment: NP :) If you need to support IE8 and/or below you should use jQuery 1.9 instead

Comment: Actually JSON must exist in IE8 standard mode. Are you using Compatibility View Mode?

Answer (score 3):

To provide an answer (since this was still unanswered), from the jQuery 2.0 documentation:

> As promised, this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6,
>   7, and 8 browsers.

If you wish to use jQuery in IE8 or less, you'll have to use jQuery 1.9.